# How to convert empty valued xml elements to PowerShell Dictionary

Tags: xml, powershell, dictionary, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to convert following xml file into PowerShell dictionary.

```
<configuration>
    <environment id="Test">
        <client>ABC</client>
        <type>Test</type>
        <template> </template>
        <targetmachines>
            <targetmachine>
                <name>Any</name>
                <remotedirectory>C:\ServiceDirectory</remotedirectory>
            </targetmachine>
        </targetmachines>
        <connectionStrings>
            <DB1>User ID=xx;password=xx=;</DB1>
            <DB2>User ID=yy;password=yy=;</DB2>
        </connectionStrings>
    </environment>
</configuration>
```

Here is my powershell script:

```
$environmentId = "Test"
$configxml = [xml] (Get-Content "xmlfile")   

$keyValuePairs = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$configxml.SelectNodes("descendant::configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]") | Where-Object {$_.Value} |
ForEach-Object {
                $keyValuePairs.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value)
                }
Write-Output $keyValuePairs
```

I'm getting following output:

```
Key                                                                      Value                                                                  
---                                                                      -----                                                                  
client                                                                   ABC                                                                    
type                                                                     Test                                                                   
name                                                                     Any                                                                    
remotedirectory                                                          C:\ServiceDirectory                                                    
DB1                                                                      User ID=xx;password=xx=;                                               
DB2                                                                      User ID=yy;password=yy=;
```

The above PowerShell script is working fine. But i want following output. The difference here is we have extra key called "template" which has empty value. I want to convert empty value elements to dictionary.

```
Key                                                                      Value                                                                  
---                                                                      -----                                                                  
client                                                                   ABC                                                                    
type                                                                    Test 
template                                                                                                                                      
name                                                                     Any                                                                    
remotedirectory                                                          C:\ServiceDirectory                                                    
DB1                                                                      User ID=xx;password=xx=;                                               
DB2                                                                      User ID=yy;password=yy=;
```

Can someone please suggest me how to update my powershell script. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `.//configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']//*[not(*)]`

Comment: Hi, Getting following error,
Exception calling "SelectNodes" with "1" argument(s): 
"'descendant::configuration/environment[@id='Test‌​']/descendant::*[not‌​(*)]' has 
an invalid token."

Comment: I do not know why, but StackOverflow insert two unprintable characters after `not`. You need to remove them.

Comment: Could you please post complete solution

Comment: Those inserted characters are `U+200C` _Zero Width Non-Joiner_ and `U+200B` _Zero Width Space_ between `not` and `(*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$xml = [xml]'<configuration>
    <environment id="Test">
        <client>ABC</client>
        <type>Test</type>
        <template> </template>
        <targetmachines>
            <targetmachine>
                <name>Any</name>
                <remotedirectory>C:\ServiceDirectory</remotedirectory>
            </targetmachine>
        </targetmachines>
        <connectionStrings>
            <DB1>User ID=xx;password=xx=;</DB1>
            <DB2>User ID=yy;password=yy=;</DB2>
        </connectionStrings>
    </environment>
</configuration>'
$environmentId = "Test"

$dictionary = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]'
$xml.SelectNodes("//configuration/environment[@id='$environmentId']//*[not(*)]") | `
  % { $dictionary.Add($_.Name,$_.InnerText) }
```

**Dictionary content**

```
Key                Value                   
---                -----                   
client             ABC                     
type               Test                    
template                                   
name               Any                     
remotedirectory    C:\ServiceDirectory     
DB1                User ID=xx;password=xx=;
DB2                User ID=yy;password=yy=;
```

Comment: Dyl, Thank you so much. it is working fine. Could you please tell me what is _*[not(*)]") | `_ meaning ? Thanks again.